# Whats wrong with my statement in js.php file

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

Trying to do a simple html change with a ternary operator. Page loads fine and only thing missing in html is the #np_msg element. Not sure what is wrong here. This the code snippet from

**form.js.php**

```
    var toprighttext = <?php echo ($company_id==69) ? 'Please add an organization.' : 'Please add nonprofit.'; ?>
    jQuery('#np_msg').html(toprighttext).show();
```

**html that appears**

```
<div class="donationrequestformRight">
        <div class="donationrequestinputWrap clearfix"> 
            <label class="donationrequestlabel" for="donationrequest_nonprofit">

        Your Organization 
                    <span>*</span>
    </label>
            <input type="text" class="donationrequestinputbox correct" name="general[np_name]" id="donationrequest_nonprofit" value="">
            <input type="hidden" name="general[np_id]" id="np_id" value="0" style="display:block;">
                            <div id="np_msg" style="display: none;"></div>
            <p style="float: right;font-size: 14px;font-weight: bold;">Can't find your organization? <a href="javascript:void(0);" id="addNP">Add it here</a>.</p>
        </div>  
        <div class="donationrequestinputWrap last clearfix">
    <input type="hidden" name="drop_np_contact_id" id="drop_np_contact_id" value="0">   
                <input type="hidden" name="general[np_contact_id]" id="np_contact_id_final" value="0">
                    <label class="donationrequestlabel" for="donationrequest_contact">

        Contact Information 
                    <span>*</span></label>
            <div id="contact_div">

            </div>
            <div id="np_con_load" style="float: right;"></div>

            <p style="float: left;font-size: 13px;font-weight: normal;">
        Click <a href="javascript:void(0);" id="addNPContact">here</a>

        to add your contact information.
                </p>
            <div id="contact_msg" style="display: none;"></div>
        </div>      
        <div class="darkgreybox clearfix" id="details_info" style="display: none;"></div>
        </div>
```

Comment: What's the HTML for the np_msg element look like?

Comment: Does that really need to be inserted using JQuery? It sounds like it would be easier to print it as part of the page with just PHP to me...(move the echo statement to inside #np_msg)

Comment: Katana I agree, I might make that change instead.

Answer (score 1):

```
add quotes

var toprighttext = "<?php echo ($company_id==69) ? 'Please add an organization.' : 'Please add nonprofit.'; ?>";
        jQuery('#np_msg').html(toprighttext).show();
```

Comment: This did not fix it, and the page crashed.

Comment: I don't see why that would crash. However, your code don't work because you are doing: var toprighttext = Please add an organization. instead of var toprighttext = "Please add an organization."; As you can see, the second option is a JS string and your code is not because of the quotes that define a string are missing